# How to set Auto increment Integer in Oracle Data Modeler

Tags: oracle, oracle-sql-data-modeler, oracle21c

I am looking for an option to select or add to make the primary key which is an Integer generate itself, adding to the previous value of 1. I don't need code  SQL , just where can I do this in Oracle Data Modeler. Version 23.1.0.087

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open column's **properties** and set **auto increment** property ON:

[image]

Comment: Interesting, there is no such option for me [link](https://imgur.com/a/KG8XFIO)

Comment: Where did you take that screenshot from? Is it **SQL Developer**, or is it **SQL Developer Data Modeler**? Two different tools! (Mine is from SQL Developer Data Modeler.

Comment: SQL Developer Data Modeler

Comment: Interesting, as you said. We're running the same version (23.1.0.087).

Comment: I FOUND THIS! It was in the physical model and it explains a lot. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Great, I'm glad you found it! Thank you for the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

You can add it in SQL Developer. Open your table - click on Columns tab - click on pencil icon - add column (ID) - click on Identity Column tab and define your ID. When finished - OK
[image]